# Laravel 5 - softDeleting a user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What will happen to the related data when I softdeletes a user? For example I have a donations table where we tracks all the donations given by the users for each campaigns.

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Schema of donations table

```
Schema::create('donations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('campaign_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->float('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

So if a user a softdeleted then how the total amount for a campaign is going to get affected. Also there is a comments table which tracks all the comments used by the user. We are using softdelete so that we can reactivate the account later. Is this a good method in the current scenario or can I use a status field in the users table to deactivate or reactivate users.

Comment: I would suggest using an other timestamp called deleted_at, if this is NULL then the user is not deleted else the user is deleted. You can always set the deleted_at field back to NULL when you want to reactivate the account

Comment: The donations must be persisted in the database IMO. Even if the associated user is deleted. I think, you are using the apropriate method here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing will happen with related data when user is soft deleted. The only thing that soft delete does is set column `deleted_at` (of users table) to current datetime (as opposed to null). I don't  know how you count total amounts etc., but if those values are stored in DB, they will be untouched.

If you want to e.g. delete also all users comments when soft deleting user you can use see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) how to subscribe to deleting/deleted event and use it to trigger also deletion of related models.

Comment: the total is calculated using $campaign->donations->sum('amount')

Comment: So this will not change and count all donations that are in table, unless all users donations will be also soft deleted.

Comment: What will happen when a user who got soft deleted tries to login, is his record also get checked in the Auth controller ? Is there any way to do that, so that I can give them an option to reactivate their account

Comment: If you're using out of the box authorization, I'm fairly sure soft deleted users cannot login. This probably can be somehow overcome, but I can't give you specific answer. I would do it by requesting users email and sending message with some account reactivation link.

Comment: I am using the default authorization coming with laravel

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [soft deletes](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#soft-deleting) you do know that soft deleting will only have influence on one record, in this case, your user.

So when you soft delete a user what happens, to donations and comments?

Nothing.

You are soft deleting a user, not doing a cascade soft delete.

If you need to soft delete related data you have to do it manually